# I tried to run AutoGPT but Chrome failed to start

Tags: autogpt

Whenever it starts browsing, it gives this error:

```
SYSTEM:  Command browse_website returned: Error: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
```

Someone suggested switching default browser to firefox but it failed too.